# Set flag column based on a regular expression

Tags: sql, oracle

I have developed the following query but it does not work as expected:

```
WITH TABLE1 AS
(
SELECT 613414473 as ID,  1706014200964  as P_NUM, 119539 as d_id,  'F20.0'  AS CODE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 613414473 as ID,  1706014200964  as P_NUM, 119539 as d_id,  'F22.0'  AS CODE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 613415801 as ID,  1707045167741  as P_NUM, 115182 as d_id,  'A94.0'  AS CODE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 613415801 as ID,  1707045167741  as P_NUM, 115182 as d_id,  NULL     AS CODE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 613417084 as ID,  1702038456441  as P_NUM, 6541   as d_id,  'E79'    AS CODE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 613417084 as ID,  1702038456421  as P_NUM, 6541   as d_id,  'I10'    AS CODE FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 613418372 as ID,  1706226211517  as P_NUM, 25727  as d_id,  'F32.9'  AS CODE FROM DUAL )
SELECT T1.* 
    , CASE when regexp_like( CODE, 'C0[5-9]|' ||
                               'A0[0-9]|A1[0-9]|A2[0-9]|A3[0-9]|A4[0-9]|A5[0-9]|A6[0-9]|A7[0-9]|A8[0-9]|A9[0-7]|' )
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0  END AS FOUND_CODE    
FROM  TABLE1 T1;
```

I want codes which are like `C0[5-9]%` or `A0[0-97]` to be flagged with value 1, and then for the same `p_num`, if at least one code was found to set all the flags for that `p_num` to 1.

Example output of the above:

```
| 613414473|1706014200964|119539|F20.0|0|
| 613414473|1706014200964|119539|F22.0|0|
| 613415801|1707045167741|115182|A94.0|1|
| 613415801|1707045167741|115182|NULL |1|
| 613417084|1702038456441|6541  |E79  |0|
| 613417084|1702038456421|6541  |I10  |0|
| 613418372|1706226211517|25727 |F32.9|0|
```

How can I modify my query to get that output? And is there a better regular expression I can use?

Comment: That isn't the output from your current query, so presumably it's the output you want to achieve; but then why ie the row with `E79` flagged as 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, the regular expression pattern should be

```
'^(C0[5-9]|A[0-8][0-9]|A9[0-7])'
```

The `^` anchors to the start of the value, and the parentheses allow any of the pipe-separated patterns to match; and the patterns are simplified, as A00 to A89 can be handles in one go.

That flags the same single row as your original query. The next stage is to move that into a subquery, and then use an analytic function partitioned by the `p_num` which you want to be common:

```
max(found_code) over (partition by p_num)
```

So together that becomes (with additional rows to match a different rule):

```
with table1 (id, p_num, d_id, code) as
(
  select 613414470, 1706014200960, 119530, 'D99'   from dual union all
  select 613414471, 1706014200960, 119531, 'C05'   from dual union all
  --
  select 613414473, 1706014200964, 119539, 'F20.0' from dual union all
  select 613414473, 1706014200964, 119539, 'F22.0' from dual union all
  select 613415801, 1707045167741, 115182, 'A94.0' from dual union all
  select 613415801, 1707045167741, 115182, null    from dual union all
  select 613417084, 1702038456441, 6541  , 'E79'   from dual union all
  select 613417084, 1702038456421, 6541  , 'I10'   from dual union all
  select 613418372, 1706226211517, 25727 , 'F32.9' from dual 
)
select id, p_num, d_id, code, max(found_code) over (partition by p_num) as found_code
from (
  select t1.*
       , case when regexp_like( code, '^(C0[5-9]|A[0-8][0-9]|A9[0-7])' )
              then 1
              else 0
         end as found_code
  from table1 t1
);

           ID         P_NUM          D_ID CODE     FOUND_CODE
------------- ------------- ------------- ----- -------------
    613414470 1706014200960        119530 D99               1
    613414471 1706014200960        119531 C05               1
    613414473 1706014200964        119539 F20.0             0
    613414473 1706014200964        119539 F22.0             0
    613415801 1707045167741        115182 A94.0             1
    613415801 1707045167741        115182                   1
    613417084 1702038456441          6541 E79               0
    613417084 1702038456421          6541 I10               0
    613418372 1706226211517         25727 F32.9             0
```